# Generate txt from DF from file name

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Good evening

I have the following data frame

```
val dfInfo = df.select(col("Info"), col("eventLineage.filename")).
      groupBy(col("consistencyInfo"), col("filename")).agg(count(col("filename")))
        .orderBy(col("filename"))
```

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Info  |filename                                       |count(filename)|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file01|1              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file01|2              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file01|2              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file01|5              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file02|1              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file02|2              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file02|2              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file02|5              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I generate a txt or create a data frame with the data separated by the file name.
In other words, I want to create a df/txt with the data from file01
and a txt with the file02 file details.

I would like something like that

file01

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Info  |filename                                       |count(filename)|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file01|1              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file01|2              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file01|2              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file01|5              |
```

file02

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Info  |filename                                       |count(filename)|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file02|1              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file02|2              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file02|2              |
|[1234]|file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file02|5              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you know `file01` and `file02` at development time?

Comment: @ernest_k Yes, i know

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to just filter/select: `file02 = df where filename ends with "file02"`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you are trying to create `DataFrame` per unique value in column 'fileName'.

You can't `spilt` a `DataFrame`, so you will have to apply transformation on original DataFrame for every child DataFrame you want to create.

If you know there are only two values, then

```
df1 = dfInfo.filter(col("filename") === "file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file01" // or endsWith "1"
df1 = dfInfo.filter(col("filename") === "file:/home/serasa.intranet/c81484a/teste/file01" // or endsWith "2"
```

And if unknown then you can write a generic function like below:

```
  //returns Array of [column value as String and DataFrame]
  def generateFrames(df: DataFrame, by: Column): Array[(String, DataFrame)] = {
    val distinctRecords = df.select(by).distinct().cache()
    if (distinctRecords.filter(by.isNull).count() == 0)
      distinctRecords.collect().map(r => (r.get(0).toString, df.filter(by === r.get(0))))
    else
  //If column contains any null value.
      distinctRecords.filter(by.isNotNull).collect().map(r => (r.get(0).toString, df.filter(by === r.get(0)))) :+ ("Null", df.filter(by.isNull))
  }
```

so in your example it would be:

```
generateFrames(dfInfo, col("filename")).foreach(v => {
    println(s"Invoking show on  DF: ${v._1}")
    v._2.show()
  }
  )
```

***Note***: If you are going to invoke action on each individual `DataFrame`'s lineage separately, I would suggest you to cache it first.